# MVVM - DataGrid not displaying errors, using ErrorDataInfo

Tags: c#, mvvm, error-handling, datagrid

In my WPF application, using MVVM Light, I use a `DataGrid` to display datas from a specific object collection.

As requirement I had seperated the headers in a first list, and the complete object collection in another one.

After reading lots of tutorials, posts, blogs... it appeared that `ErrorDataInfo` has to be placed in the ViewModel to manage the model properties error.

Here, as a try, I want to display a very basic error as you'll see in the code.

The app process is that the user choose a csv file, this file is converted to my object collection and then displayed in the `DataGrid`. The cells on error state should be displayed at this time (and the error message in a ToolTip).

I've tried many things but my `DataGrid` is still not displaying cells in errors.

Here is my ViewModel code :

```
 public class ImportViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
            {       
                #region Validation
                public string Error
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                }

                public string this[string columnName]
                {
                    get
                    {
                        string result = null;

                        if (null != ListOfObjects)
                        {
                            if (_imp.ListOfHeaders.Where(x => x.Name == "EAN Code")
                                 .ToString() == columnName)
                                if (ListOfObjects.Select(x => x.ean_cod).Single().Length > 3)
                                    result = "Code must not be more than 3 digits";
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                }
```

And my View xaml code

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfObjects, 
              Mode=TwoWay, 
              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
              ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
              NotifyOnValidationError=True}">

                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
                                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

                 </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
```

Thx for your help.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the object model that is contained in `ListOfObjects`? I think that is the object that needs to implement `IDataErrorInfo`